# The ForeignKey always Null

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity

I think it was an error somewhere. But where? I have a class. As follows. I have one table definition. User type, role identity as there are types.

There is no error, but the "def_ROLEID" and "def_COMPANYID" null. But ROLEID and COMPANYID not null. Where is error?

```
public class def_user: Base
    {
        [Key]
        public int USERID{ get; set; }
        public string NAME{ get; set; }
        public string USERCODE{ get; set; }

        public string PWD{ get; set; }

        public int ROLEID{ get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ROLEID")]
        public def_table def_ROLEID { get; set; }

        public int COMPANYID{ get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("COMPANYID")]
        public def_company def_COMPANYID { get; set; }
    }
```

Finally my repostroy class as below.

```
  public virtual List<T> GetMany(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where)
        {
            return ApplyInclude().Where(where).ToList();
        }
```

And my method:

```
 public Response<Model.def_user> List(Model.def_user usr)
        {
            var result_def_user  = new Response<Model.def_user>();
            result_def_user  .List = def_Repository.GetMany
                (
                    x =>
                    usr.USERCODE!= null ? x.USERCODE== def.USERCODE:
                    usr.PWD!= null ? x.PWD== usr.PWD :
                    usr.USERID >=0
                );
            return result_def_user ;
        }
```

I edit the metod and code.

```
 public void Include(params string[] paths)
    {
        _paths = paths;
    }

public virtual List<T> GetMany(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where)
    {
        return ApplyInclude().Where(where).ToList();
    }

  def_Repository.Include(new[] { "ROLID" });
  var query = def_Repository.GetMany(x => x.USERID> 0);
```

Now; i am getting error "The context cannot be used while the model is being created.";

How can i do?

Answer (score 0):

Make your navigation properties virtual for lazy-loading:

```
[ForeignKey("ROLEID")]
public virtual def_table def_ROLEID { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("COMPANYID")]
public virtual def_company def_COMPANYID { get; set; }
```

If you want to load related roles and companies in one query, then use eager loading (it should be done in repository `GetMany` method). Something like

```
context.def_users.Where(...)
                 .Include(u => u.def_ROLEID)
                 .Include(u => u.def_COMPANYID)
```

Suggested reading: [Loading Related Entities in Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx)

NOTE: I suggest you to improve naming standards of your code. It's better to use `RoleId`, `CompanyId` for keys, `User`, `Role`, `Company` for class names. `def_ROLEID` and `def_COMPANYID` are extremely confusing names - they look like ids, not like related entities. Use `Company` and `Role` instead. See [C# Naming Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: No, the ROLEID has value.  The def_ROLEID is null.

Comment: @caras Just make navigation properties virtual if you want lazy-loading to work, or use eager loading when getting users

Comment: i understand. But how can i include the def_table and def_company?

Comment: @caras sample above. Link has more samples. Check your `ApplyInclude` method